# Switch and while combination using scanf, how to avoid multiple input

Tags: c, input, while-loop, switch-statement, buffer

In this `switch` and `while` combination, when I press 'a' or 'b' it's fine but I don't want the program to print `1` and `2` when user inputs 'ab'.

How can I print an error message when user enters an input with more than one character?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char move;

    while (move != 'd') {
        printf("enter a move :  ");
        scanf(" %c", &move);
        switch (move) {
            case 'a':
                printf("1\n");
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("2\n");
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("3 \n");
        }  // switch
    }      // while
}
```

Sample output :

```
enter a move : a
1
enter a move : b
2
enter a move : ab
1
enter a move : 2
```

The program should print error message when I input 'ab', 'ac' or 'bc', or similar.

Comment: If you want to handle strings rather than individual characters, then you need to read strings.  You can do this with `scanf`, or you can use `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of `fgets` to parse inputs. Avoiding the common edge cases gets somewhat trickier, you need to handle the newline character that will also be parsed from your input as you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you need to clear the input to prepare for the next loop, since `fgets` also parses `\n` you need to avoid handling it in some cases, just to to mention a few common cases.

Here's how you could do it:

You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/S6Uh3mrHX

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

```
int main() {
    char move[20] = {};
    while (move[0] != 'd') {
        printf("enter a move :  ");
        // parse and check fgets return to validate input
        if (fgets(move, sizeof move, stdin) != NULL) {
            // if we have more than 2 chars, error, fgets also parses \n and strlen counts it
            if (strlen(move) > 2) {
                printf("Error, invalid input\n");
                // if the \n character wasn't already parsed we need to handle it
                if (!strchr(move, '\n')) {
                    int c;
                    // this just clears the stdin input buffer
                    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
                }
                // Since we got an error, let's reset our target buffer
                move[0] = 0;
            }
        }
        switch (move[0]) {
            case 'a':
                printf("1\n");
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("2\n");
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("3 \n");
        }  // switch
    }      // while
}
```

---

If you have to use `scanf`, however, here's a possible solution:

You can try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/Hcu8dlb04G

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char move = 0;  // don't forget to initialize, accessing an unitialized
                    // variable is UB (1
    while (move != 'd') {
        printf("enter a move :  ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &move) == 1) {
            int c;
            if (getchar() != '\n') {  // if more character were inputed other than newline
                printf("Error, invalid input\n");                // print error
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}   // clear input buffer
                move = 0;  // reset target variable
            }
            switch (move) {
                case 'a':
                    printf("1\n");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("2\n");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    printf("3 \n");
            }  // switch
        }      // while
    }
}
```

You still may need to handle other edge cases, for exampe, let's say the user inputs `j`, no input error is issued, it just jumps to the next input loop (you can handle this in the `switch`), you may also want to add support for upper case letters.

---

<sup>1 - UB: Undefined Behavior, definition: https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3</sup>